# taking Input field value in session variable and showing at action page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have following code at *s.php*:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { 
    $_SESSION['p'] = $_POST['p'];
} 
?> 

<form action="s2.php" method"post">
<input type="text" name="p"/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

And At *s2.php*

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
<?php
echo 'This is especially for ='.$_SESSION['p'];
?>
```

After entering value in input field and clicking the submit button, it take to next page and change the browser link to some thing like `/s2.php?p=inputvalue&Submit=Submit`.

I want to show the value at *s2.php* that was entered in the input field at *s.php*.

I have placed the `echo` code, but nothing shows up (I have tested on different servers).

Comment: `method"post"` change to `method="post"`

Comment: oH, it was my mistake. I checked by fixing this but it didn't solve the problem. Nothing is showing up at the action page. However i see a change when i fix this. "browser link is not being changed now".. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Thank you.

Solution: at s2.php (action page) we have to use the following code:

```
echo 'This is especially for ='.$_POST['p'];
```

Thanks

Comment: Why putting it in the $_SESSION then?